# How can I show different kafka to my confluent?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I install confluent and  it has own kafka.

I want to change kafka from own to another?

Which `.properties or whatelse` file I must change to look different kafka.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you update your question to be a bit clearer please. What component are you wanting to change? You need to be more specific.

Comment: What producers/consumers are you using with your Kafka cluster, that you want to use with a different one?

Comment: just I want to consumer , I mean I want to read from topic for jdbc link that topic is on different kafka

Comment: OK, so you're talking about Kafka Connect reading from a different Kafka cluster?

Comment: yes you r right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Kafka Connect worker configuration, you need to set [`bootstrap.servers`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#common-configuration-properties) to point to the broker(s) on your source Kafka cluster.

You can only connect to one source Kafka cluster per Kafka Connect worker. If you need to stream data from multiple Kafka clusters, you would run multiple Kafka Connect workers.

---

**Edit** If you're using Confluent CLI then the Kafka Connect worker config is taken from `etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`.

Comment: in consumer.properties file ?

Comment: Which file you need to edit depends on how you're running Kafka Connect. See https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#standalone-mode.